# Angular application deployment

Tags: php, angular, symfony

I am currently working on a web application project, and now I want to push it on a production server.
This project consists of a Rest API in PHP 7.1 (Symfony) and an Angular 2 client.
When I run the application locally, everything works fine.

But on the production server, when I launch my browser, I get
[image: this error] in the console.
I don't know where the error may come from, and despite my many research on the net, I'm still blocked.

Has anyone ever met this error and could help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-production-mode)?

Comment: Yes, I tried this but nothing changed...

Comment: (You also may want to use the tag **Angular** and not Angularjs if you are referring to Angular 2 / 4, so you can reach more people that can help you with your issue)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using angular-cli ? What command did you use to package and deploy your project ?

Did it contain :

```
ng serve --prod
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I'm using Angular-cli and I use the command "ng serve --host 172.16.232.133 --port 4200 --disable-host-check". I tried to add --prod but nothing changed.

Comment: So , in production server , does it render ? I mean , is it a problem with the API or the app files paths?

Comment: Actually, I don't know the origin of the problem. I just know that is linked with the websocket 'socketjs' but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The render is done, I can see my page with the elements, but this error appears.